# QGIS Vector Layers

Tags: qgis-3, vector, mapping

Why does the Columbia River nearly perfectly follow the OR-WA border? What characteristics do vector layers have that allow this?

Comment: I would dare to say it's vice versa: OR-WA border nearly perfectly follows Columbia River. First there was a river, then there was a border.

Answer (score 1):

To quote [Wikipedia article on Columbia river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbia_River)

> The Columbia makes a sharp bend to the west at the Washington–Oregon
>   border. The river defines that border for the final 309 miles (497 km)
>   of its journey.

It's in the law and due to history https://web.archive.org/web/20100527193305/http://www.oregon.gov/DSL/NAV/navigwaterways.shtml
You will see the content refer to "Oregon Admission act" (1859) https://www.oregonlegislature.gov/bills_laws/Pages/OreConstAdmission.aspx